# How to implement CorePlot in iPhone project

Tags: iphone, charts

Hai All,
I'm downloading the source code from this link

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

In this sample application CorePlot-CocoaTouch.XCodeproject has shown in red color(there is nothing).where should i download the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.XCodeproject(static library)and install it into this sample application.Please help me out to do this..

Thanks and Regards

Renuga

Answer (score 0):

You get Core Plot from http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/.